# PHP using %string

Tags: php, switch-statement

Can I not do this?

```
        $png = array();
        $jpeg = array();
        $jpg = array();
        $gif = array();

        if($dirOpen = opendir('imagefiles'))
        {
            while(($imagee = readdir($dirOpen))!==false)
            { 
                if ($imagee == '.' or $imagee == '..') continue;
                echo var_dump($imagee);  
                switch($imagee)
                {
                    case "%.png": $png[] = $imagee; break;
                    case "%.jpeg": $jpeg[] = $imagee; break;
                    case "%.jpg": $jpg[] = $imagee; break;
                    case "%.gif": $gif[] = $imagee; break;
                    default: echo "error";
                }
            }
            print_r($jpg);
            closedir($dirOpen);
        }

        $imagesss =  array_merge($png, $jpeg, $jpg, $gif);
```

I'm trying to sort the images by type, so if I get something like KJFEORHGkjheilg.jpg then it goes to case '%.jpg', but apparently not. why?

Comment: is this correct? *`"KJFEORHGkjheilg.jpg then it goes to case '%.png'"`* - what error(s) are you getting?

Comment: @blurfus thx, edited.

Comment: No, you cannot use `%` as a wildcard in `switch` case, nor is there any other wildcard. Just get the extension and use that in the `switch` cases.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an operator inside a string, you cannot do comparisons inside a case .. case IS the comparison .. And you're using a division operator `%` as a wildcard at that ..  I would (assuming you only had one `.` in your file name) do something like this using `explode`:

```
switch( explode('.', $imagee)[1] )
{
    case "png": $png[] = $imagee; break;
    case "jpeg": $jpeg[] = $imagee; break;
    case "jpg": $jpg[] = $imagee; break;
    case "gif": $gif[] = $imagee; break;
    default: echo "error";
}
```

Explained:

`explode('.', 'imagename.png')` will create an array

```
[0]imagename
[1]png
```

So `explode('.', 'imagename.png')[1]` will be `png`

**UPDATE**

If you had more than 1 `.` in your file name .. you could do a little logic before hand.

```
$im_length = ( count( explode('.', $imagee) ) - 1);

$imagee = explode('.', $imagee)[$im_length];

switch( $imagee )
{
    case "png": $png[] = $imagee; break;
    case "jpeg": $jpeg[] = $imagee; break;
    case "jpg": $jpg[] = $imagee; break;
    case "gif": $gif[] = $imagee; break;
    default: echo "error";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use `%` as a wildcard in `switch` case, nor is there any other wildcard. Just get the extension and use that in the `switch` cases. For instance with [pathinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo).

Here's your code using that:

```
$png  = [];
$jpeg = [];
$jpg  = [];
$gif  = [];

if ($dirHandle = opendir('imagefiles')) {
    while (($filename = readdir($dirHandle))) { 
        switch (strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))) {
            case "png"  : $png[]  = $filename; break;
            case "jpeg" : $jpeg[] = $filename; break;
            case "jpg"  : $jpg[]  = $filename; break;
            case "gif"  : $gif[]  = $filename; break;
        }
    }
    closedir($dirHandle);
}

$imageFiles = array_merge($png, $jpeg, $jpg, $gif);
```

Since you merge the images file all together at the end you could also do:

```
$imageTypes = ["png", "jpeg", "jpg", "gif"];
$imageFiles = [];

if ($dirHandle = opendir('imagefiles')) {
    while (($filename = readdir($dirHandle))) { 
        $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if (in_array($extension, $imageTypes)) {
            $imageFiles[] = $filename; 
        }
    }
    closedir($dirHandle);
}
```